# Windows Phone 8 checking If the stackpanel is in the visible area

Tags: windows-phone-8

It's a very simple question. I have a number of stackpanels inside of a scrollview. I want them to raise an event when there are visible to the user(via scrolling).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/01/18/elements-visibility-inside-scrollviewer.aspx) out. It shows how to determine if your element is in the ScrollViewers viewport.

```
// position of your visual inside the scrollviewer    
GeneralTransform childTransform = ContainedObject.TransformToAncestor(ScrollViewerObj);
Rect rectangle = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0,0),ContainedObject.RenderSize));

//Check if the elements Rect intersects with that of the scrollviewer's
Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ScrollViewerObj.RenderSize),rectangle);
//if result is Empty then the element is not in view
if (result == Rect.Empty)
{
//....
}
else
{
//obj is partially Or completely visible
//skip or bring obj in view.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the missing piece of the solution. Although I had to change the code from the link. There is no Rect.Intersect method. There is Intersect method but its not static. Anyway thank you again.